# How to convert two arrays of strings to the array of objects like key and value with particular keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

I need to convert two arrays of strings with the same length:

```
const arr1 = ['Jessica', 'Ben', 'Samantha', 'John', 'Sandy'];
const arr2 = ['21', '45', '34', '90', '67'];
```

And in the end i need to get this array with particular keys name, age:

```
const result = [
{ name: 'Jessica', age: '21'}, 
{ name: 'Ben', age: '45'}, 
{ name: 'Samantha', age: '34'},
{ name: 'John', age: '90' },
{ name: 'Sandy', age: '67' },
];
```

Can you tell me please how can i do it?

Comment: of course! and i did not find a good solution, help me if you know it

Comment: Please post your attempt for solving this, and if you face any problem with it, we can help you.

Comment: @jocoders Then please share your attempt in question. SO is not a **get code for free site**

Comment: but it is not the same question that you have posted!

Comment: @jocoders, Here you can get the result you want https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/KKpmKPM

Comment: Updated the duplicate which is same as your question

Comment: Anyone who knows how to use a loop, and how to assign object properties with “dynamic” names, should be able to easily solve this. (And anyone who lacks knowledge of either of the two, should maybe go read up on / research such basics?)

Answer (score 5):

Loop through the `arr1`. You get the names and the index. Based on index, get the `ages` from `arr2` considering `name` and age array indexes are same

```js
const arr1 = ['Jessica', 'Ben', 'Samantha', 'John', 'Sandy'];
const arr2 = ['21', '45', '34', '90', '67']; 

const result = arr1.map((name, index) => {
  return {
    'name': name,
    'age': arr2[index]
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: First, missing explanation. Second, please do not spoonfeed answers.

Comment: Add an explanation `arr1.map((name, i) => ({name, age: arr2[i]}));` and you can get upvotes.

Comment: Downvote does not mean incorrect. It means not required. Also vote is for missing explanation. Just putting code is not answer. Please explain what and why you have done

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @adiga how did you do??

Comment: Click on the link in the previous comment